# How to create a histogram with real values

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to create a histogram to plot real values such as

values = [17.711934920693217, 21.962771788060337, 24.570616100324703, 18.862357360933803, 19.35670692079581, 16.21371067895039, 15.723282991698177, 13.420629746222984, 10.346425858632237].

I'm using pyplot.hist but all I obtain is an empty histogram. Is it possibile to plot these values directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean in your question by "real values", do you mean setting the heights of the bars? an expected result would be good.

However, you could possibly want to use plt.bar instead

```
plt.bar(range(len(values)), values)
```

[image]